# Django Rest Framework - POST request invokes GET request (localhost)

Tags: django, rest, post, django-rest-framework, request

When I try to access http://localhost:8000/api/articles/ it works fine.

When I try to access http://localhost:8000/api/articles/1 it works fine.

When I try to access http://localhost:8000/api/articles/create Django thinks that I am trying to perform a GET request (`'get': 'retrieve'`). What am I doing wrong?

**errors** `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'`

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='list'),
    path('<pk>/', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='detail'),
    path('create/', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}) ,name='create'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        articles = query_filter(request, ArticleViewSet.queryset)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        articles = formatter(serializer.data)
        return Response(articles)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        article = get_object_or_404(ArticleViewSet.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)
        article = formatter([serializer.data])
        return Response(article)

    def create(self, request):
        articles = ArticleViewSet.queryset
        articles.create(title=request.data['title'], body=request.data['body'])
        article = articles.last()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)
        article = formatter([serializer.data])
        return Response(article)
```

Also when I switch the positions of `retrieve` and `create` in the urlpatterns shown below, I get this error `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='list'),
    path('create/', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='create'),
    path('<pk>/', ArticleViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `articles.create(` be `articles.objects.create(`?

Comment: @RedCricket I'll fix that but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying with `http://localhost:8000/api/articles/create`, you are actually making [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request. That is why you are seeing the error(`"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed.".`). If you want to make post request, then you need to use api tools like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). If you use postman, try like this:

[image]

And your second url pattern is correct. because if you keep `<pk>/` before `create/`, django interprets that you are calling `<pk>/`(should be `<int:pk>`)url with argument `create`(which is a string), when you are actually calling the create method. And when it tries to convert it to integer(as primary key is an autofield), it throws `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'` exception.

Answer (score 1):

Create method doesn't not support get action that's why you're getting error `{"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."}`. Alternative you can try **ModelViewset**  that provides default `create()`, `retrieve()`, `update()`, `partial_update()`, `destroy()` and `list()` actions.

Either you can create **get_serailzer()** method using that you can get browsable API with JSON and HTML form through that you can do POST action.

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ArticleSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        articles = ArticleViewSet.queryset
        articles.create(title=request.data['title'], body=request.data['body'])
        article = articles.last()
        **serializer = self.get_serializer(article, many=False)**
        from pyreadline.logger import formatter
        article = formatter([serializer.data])
        return Response(article)
```

[Browsable API Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I was using slashes at the end and that when I was sending request I wasn't adding slashes at the end. So simply I deleted   end slashes from django urls